# python multiprocess run same process multiple times after its termination - AssertionError: cannot start a process twice

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new to python multiprocessing and kindly ask to get some insight how  to run a process consecutive more then once after its termination.
In below example I need to rerun a longer task each 10seconds interval. Works fine doing it without multiprocessing.

As I fail to get it running via python multiprocessing, kindly ask for insight.

many thanks

christian

functional code without multiprocessing

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import multiprocessing

def task(i):
    print("task : ",i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i=0
    old_run = 0.0
    while True:
       now=time.time()
       if (now - old_run >10):
         old_run=now
         task(i)                  <<< goal is to get this done via multiprocess
       print("main:", i)
       i=i+1
       time.sleep (1)
```

Mine unsuccessful code below is ending-up into "AssertionError: cannot start a process twice"

non-functional code with multiprocessing

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import multiprocessing

def task(i: int):
    print("task : ",i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    i=0
    old_run = 0.0
    while True:
       now=time.time()
       if (now - old_run >10):
         old_run=now
         processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=task,args=(i,)))
         for process in processes:
            process.start()
            process.join()
            process.terminate()
       print("main:", i)
       i=i+1
       time.sleep (1)
```

Output of the failing multiprocssing code snippet

```
`behn@rpi2:~ $ ./multi.py

task :  0
main: 0
main: 1
main: 2
main: 3
main: 4
main: 5
main: 6
main: 7
main: 8
main: 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/behn/./multi.py", line 22, in <module>
    process.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 115, in start
    assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: cannot start a process twice`
```

Comment: Are your tasks expected to run longer than 10s? Or in other words: do multiple of them run in parallel?

Comment: Hi Klaus,thanks. Indeed the task is for sure shorter then 10secs. approx. 1-2 secs in total, as it is a web-query. Have a max-retry in the web-query as well, to avoid running infinity when web-server fails to respond. to your question: Or in other words: do multiple of them run in parallel? the answer will be: no

Comment: Then, where's the advantage for multi-processing?

Comment: The script I am doing is controlling the can-bus of an inverter. Somehow over time many aspects got added like mqtt pub/sub, uart to a BMS, web-hooks. unluckely, the script stops operating correctly after running a couple of hours. the goal of multi-processing was to help with failure isolation - to keep the parts running which operate without issues.

Answer (score 0):

just answering myself..

simplified code:

```
q_do_auth_and_query = multiprocessing.Queue()
while True:
   now=time.time()
   if (now - last_sems_run > 15):
      last_sems_run=now
      mp_do_auth_and_query = multiprocessing.Process(target=sems.do_auth_and_query,args=(token,q_do_auth_and_query))
      mp_do_auth_and_query.start()
   while (not q_do_auth_and_query.empty()):
      q=q_do_auth_and_query.get()
```